# Link to an external file in Joomla - work only in test

Tags: redirect, joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla2.5, http-status-code-303

I have a very strainge issue with Joomla 2.5 and I can't find any answer. 
I have a page with some links. Each links are like www.myhost.com/joomla/custom_dev/myscript.php?foo=bar. myscript.php is an external script which is not a part of Joomla but I need Joomla's framework for some functions.

So I use the classical code :

```
// Get Joomla! framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

It works great on my test environment.

But on the live server, I got a 404 error. With FireBug, I saw that the link to the external file doesn't work at all : it goes to a 303 redirection, then to a 404 error.
I tried many things... and now I've found what causes this issue :

```
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Without this line, there is no redirection and the link works. But I have not the framework functions (and I need them !).

I also tried to access directly to my script.

www.myhost.com/joomla/custom_dev/myscript.php?foo=bar with $mainframe->initialise() -> got a 404 error (caused by many 303 redirections)

www.myhost.com/joomla/custom_dev/myscript.php?foo=bar without $mainframe->initialise() -> no error, displays what can be displayed without Joomla's framework...

I hope I was clear enough !

EDIT : I have deleted my custom 404 page, and the true 404 reason is that the category is not found. When I try www.myhost.com/joomla/custom_dev/another_script.php I have no error.

EDIT 2 : Another info : it seems that when I use $mainframe->initialise(), it automatically add the language somewhere in my URL, so it becomes www.myhost.com/joomla/custom_dev/en/myscript.php?foo=bar

Answer (score 0):

Try using this with a few tweaks and removals:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );
```

Comment: It doesn't help. The issue appears clearly when I use the "initialise()" function.